# Grep syslog configuration for remote logging entries

Tags: regex, linux, grep, syslog

I would like to grep my rsyslog configuration file to check if there are remote logging entries configured.

The lines I'd like grep to bring are as follows:

```
auth.*,authpriv.*               @loghost.example.com:10514 # One "@" means UDP
*.*                             @@loghost.example.com      # Two "@" means TCP
```

So far I have managed to produce the following regex which brings me only the lines that begin with a set of letters or an asterisk, folloqed by a dot then another set of characters or an asterisk:

```
grep "^[A-Za-z|*]*\.[A-Za-z|*]" /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

How do I get grep to identify the rest of the line correctly? Since the line could be then followed by a comma, more stuff, a sequence of spaces and a "@" sign or it could be followed by a sequence of spaces and an "@" sign.

**Edit:** What I can get so far with my current regex:

```
[root@RHEL7lab /]# grep "^[A-Za-z|*]*\.[A-Za-z|*]" /etc/rsyslog.conf
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
auth.*,authpriv.*               @loghost.example.com:10514 # One "@" means UDP
*.*                             @@loghost.example.com      # Two "@" means TCP
[root@RHEL7lab /]#
```

I want a regex that would only produce the last two lines shown above.

I have had success piping it to another grep as follows:

```
[root@RHEL7lab /]# grep "^[A-Za-z|*]*\.[A-Za-z|*]" /etc/rsyslog.conf | grep "\s@"
auth.*,authpriv.*               @loghost.example.com:10514 # One "@" means UDP
*.*                             @@loghost.example.com      # Two "@" means TCP
[root@RHEL7lab /]#
```

But I think it might me possible to do it in just one, I just lack the skills.

Comment: Please add sample lines from your syslog, what you want, what your current code does.

Comment: Try [`grep -E '^([[:alnum:]]+|\*)\.([[:alnum:]]+|\*)[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+@' file`](https://regex101.com/r/WSQP3v/1)

Comment: Or even `grep -E '^[[:alnum:]*.]+[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+@' file`

Comment: You, Mr. Wiktor Stribiżew, are a monster! That worked flawlessly! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match the lines that start with alphanumeric, `*` or `.` chars, then can have 0+ chars other than whitespace, and then having `@` after any 1+ whitespace characters:

```
grep -E '^[[:alnum:]*.]+[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+@' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSQP3v/2).

A bit more specific regex will look like

```
grep -E '^([[:alnum:]]+|\*)\.([[:alnum:]]+|\*)[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+@' file
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WSQP3v/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]*.]+` - 1 or more characters that are either alphanumeric, `*` or `.`
- `([[:alnum:]]+|\*)` - 1+ alphanumeric chars or a `*` symbol
- `\.` - a dot
- `([[:alnum:]]+|\*)` - 1+ alphanumeric chars or a `*` symbol
- `[^[:space:]]*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace chars
- `[[:space:]]+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `@` - a `@` char.

Note that `-E` option allows using POSIX ERE syntax (no need to escape `+`, e.g.).

Comment: Awesome explanation, I certainly have a lot more regex studying to do!